# Export to excel using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following function to export my data to excel sheet:

```
string filename = "Test.xls"; 
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

//Get the H`enter code here`TML for the control.
yourGrid.RenderControl(hw);
//Write the HTML back to the browser.
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
```

but excel sheet is not created. Although it shows in chrome browser bottom that excel is downloading. When it finishs downloading, I click it and it says file cant be opened. Please suggest me what is wrong in it?

[EDIT]

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 //use Response.AddHeader
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.xlsx");
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 gvLogs.RenderControl(hw);
 gvLogs.AllowPaging = false;
 gvLogs.DataBind(); // bind data 
 Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
 //need to call Flush and End methods 
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

give same error

Comment: Filename: excel expects xls, but gets html. Content type leave as is.

Comment: string filename = "Test.xls"; change to string filename = "Test.html";

Comment: Instead of Response.AppendHeader replace that with Response.AddHeader also get rid of the + "" at the end of that line

Comment: Remember you can also export to CSV which is much easier. Default files associations in Windows is to open CSV in Excel.

Comment: What is supposed to happen here? I see a HTML grid control being rendered as HTML and I see an attempt do serve an Excel file as a download. That's the actual problem (in the answers below as well, I'm sorry to say): Two different things in one Response.
What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
//use Response.AddHeader
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind(); // bind data 
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
//need to call Flush and End methods 
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: I get "xcel cannot open the file "Test.xlsx" because the file format or extension is not valid"

Comment: Change the content Type, please check

Answer (score 0):

[Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is a good library for excel import/export. You can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
 private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = "DownloadReport.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();

            //Get the HTML for the control.
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            //Write the HTML back to the browser.
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using datasouce in html so i dont have datatable

Answer (score 0):

Change the '`Response.ContentType`' value in your code as like below.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
```

Hope this will help you.